# Using already trained classifiers in Orange

Tags: cross-validation, training, orange

I know that with Orange it is possible, using the 'Test & Score" widget, to test the performance of a classifier trained on a specific training set using a different test set ('Test on test data' option).

My question is: is it possible to use a training set to train a classifier, tune its hyperparameters through cross validation on a separate validation set, and, finally, test the classification performance on a third, separate set using the already trained classifier?

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

A scheme like this should work. Namely, you pass training data directly into the the learner widget and pass its trained Model into Predictions widget along with labeled test data.

[image]